# How to re-import yammer notes to different group/network?

Tags: yammer

After export of the yammer notes (by verified administrator), how to bulk import them again if needed - to another network/group - with names, labels and content (preferably, interlinked)?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do this as there isn't a supported API available for notes. The purpose of the data export is provide access to data in a raw format which can be supported by eDiscovery tools, but re-importing content isn't a supported scenario. There is a message API for Yammer, but even this isn't designed to support import of content exported from another network since there is no way to back date the content.